# React separating pdf pages static

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

In my React App I have a long page that I want to be able to export it in PDF format. I have achieved that by using html2canvas and jsPDF. Here is just the code that exports it:

```
html2canvas(document.body).then((canvas) => {
      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var imgWidth = 210;
      var pageHeight = 295;
      var imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;
      var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm");
      var position = 0;

      doc.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      heightLeft -= pageHeight;

      while (heightLeft >= 0) {
        position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
        doc.addPage();
        doc.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      }
      doc.save("file.pdf");
    });
```

This works really well and exporting all perfectly BUT it cuts some parts of the page to 2 pieces - if the element start on Page 1 in the bottom, it finishes on Page 2 on top. I know it is because these 2 props **imgWidth, imgHeight**. Is it possible to manually put something in my components (part of the whole exporting page) to show where it should break and start another page? I mean if whole page is:

```
<Component 1/>
<Component 2/>
<Component 3/>
<Component 4/>
<Component 5/>
<Component 6/>
```

To be able to make it:

```
    <Component1 />
    <Component2 break/>
    <Component3 />
    <Component4 break/>
    <Component5 />
    <Component6 />
```

So basically I will have 3 pages PDF:
1st page:

```
<Component1 />
<Component2 break/>
```

2nd page:

```
<Component3 />
<Component4 break/>
```

3rd page:

```
<Component5 />
<Component6 />
```

UPDATE:

Here is how the cutting looks-like:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a code sandbox for this?

Comment: ''BUT it cuts some parts of the page to 2 pieces - if the element start on Page 1 in the bottom, it finishes on Page 2 on top.''

can you demonstrate this part , show a screenshot

Comment: Forgive the question, but was there something wrong with `<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/css/pdf.css">` with "print to pdf" handled by the user instead of by you?

Comment: @ZackHeisenberg Screenshot attached

Comment: @MohammedMounir No, I changed the strategy about this. I created endpoint in my back-end which is creating PDF with graphs and data tables. It is not the same as in my React application but very similar.

Comment: have you found any solution for this? I am facing the similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73772866/how-to-fix-content-cut-off-issues-in-jspdf-html2canvas

Comment: @SDK Same as my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the `break-before` CSS property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before